# Facing errors in SonarCube scan through Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to implement sonar scan in my Scala codes which are in data bricks notebook via Azure-Devops pipeline but getting below error can somebody please help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages, post the actual error text.

Answer (score 0):

The third-party FindBugs plugin is throwing an error with the following message:

> One (sub)project contains Java source files that are not compiled.

According to the [FindBugs readme](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/tree/4.0.2#compiled-code), it needs compiled code i.e. you can't just point it at the source code files. Check that you are building the code before analysing it.